# multiple bash commands in a line

Tags: bash, makefile

I'm trying to write multiple bash commands in a single line

```
source ~/.profile ; vex dl ; cd ~/dl ; make install
```

However this does'nt do anything. However when I type exit and it runs make install and dies on the first line. However when I run these separately on the command line, everything works fine. I can't see why this does'nt work. Suggestions anyone?

Comment: What is `vex`? Is it an alias defined in `.profile`?

Comment: yeah,  it's a python utility.

Comment: Aliases are expanded immediately after the input line is read, but before any part of that line is executed. It sounds like `vex` is being expanded to an old version of your alias before the `source` command defines the appropriate version.

Comment: Why do you need to do `source ~/.profile`? That's done automatically when you login, you shouldn't need to do it by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading some documentation on vex; it seems you want to run **make install**  in the virtual environment from the **dl** directory.

This is not bash issue/question but more a vex question.

Try this instead:

```
source ~/.profile ; vex dl bash -c build.sh
```

Build.sh should be script that will cd to the dl directory and run make install.
The virtual environment will "deactivate" once the script finishes.

Comment: He said that `vex` is an alias defined in his `.profile`. An alias won't be expanded if it's defined earlier on the same line.

Comment: Thanks Carlos. It looks like this is the magic line that works!
source ~/.profile ;~/bin/vex --cwd ~/dl  make install